# Is there any transparent network accelerating library?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am aware network programming can be a big trap. There are synchronous/asynchronous ways of handling sockets.

Now I have an application that uses a lot of threads with synchronous socket send/recv to server. I believe this is a very inefficient way writing network application. My questions is is there any transparent(by preload) network accelerating library that can magically replace the threads/sync model in the legacy application with a more modern epoll/async way? Just like what tcmalloc does to malloc?

thx!

==================

Okay, a brief survey seems to tell a negative answer. Then I am going to write my own accelerating library. Best luck to myself.

Comment: Threading generally speeds things up, so making one big packet out of all threads and sending it at once, would be slower.

Comment: [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) isn’t a drop-in replacement, but it is asynchronous and abstracts away the various event-based implementations.

Comment: That would be a hell of an amazing library given how different the two approaches are.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are usually used with a blocking model (i.e. wait for data to be ready) while epoll/async uses a non-blocking event driven model. While it is fairly easy to encapsulate non-blocking code into applications developed with the blocking model, it is not the other way around. To move from blocking to a non-blocking event based model you have to rethink and rewrite your application.